# How to get button size before view is load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, viewdidappear

I looking for some solution how to get size of button before view is load. I want to make button round so I try this

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGSize loopButtonSize= _loopButton.frame.size;
    _loopButton.layer.cornerRadius=loopButtonSize.height/2.0f;
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear button height: %f", loopButtonSize.height);
}
```

But this show wrong button size (1000 instead of for example 43) My button has dynamic change size so I can't use constant size values.

This works for me but it change button shape after view loading. So if I use animated load then for second appear square button which then change to round.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGSize loopButtonSize= _loopButton.frame.size;
    _loopButton.layer.cornerRadius=loopButtonSize.height/2.0f;

    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear button height: %f", loopButtonSize.height);

}
```

Any ideas how make it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code to round the button in viewDidLayoutSubviews method, since it is called just after the view is laid out you will get your button properly rounded.

Answer (score 1):

Put that code in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Yeah, you should accept @Aakash's answer. He posted his (a few seconds) before mine.